# Summing The Values Of A List Inside A List In Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm having a bit of trouble with this one bit of Python code. The challenge is as follows:

> "Write a function called sum_lists. sum_lists should take one
>   parameter, which will be a list of lists of integers. sum_lists should
>   return the sum of adding every number from every list.
>
> Below are some lines of code that will test your function. You can
>   change the value of the variable(s) to test your function with
>   different inputs.
>
> If your function works correctly, this will originally print: 78"

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
print(sum_lists(list_of_lists))
```

Here's my code that I've managed to put together so far. As is, I get an output like this:

```
def sum_lists(list_of_lists):
    result = []

    #extract what list from the bigger list
    for listnumber in list_of_lists:
        sum = 0

        #add the value of the smaller list
        for value in listnumber:
            sum += value
        result.append(sum)

        #add the result values together
        #for resultvalue in result:
        #    result += resultvalue

    return sum(result)
```

Where the values of each list are summed together but are still 3 separate values in the result = [] section:

```
[10, 26, 42]
```

When I tried `return sum(result)`I get hit with `"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".` Likewise, when I try to make another For loop and add the values of result = [] together, I get the same TypeError which is confusing because when I made a simple function and applied sum() to the return statement I got a summed output with no issues.

I'm stumped. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: The actual error message is `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` - **not** `... iterable`. The reason is that you defined `sum` as a variable which holds a number, so then `sum(result)` at the end doesn't work because `sum` is your number, not a function. Please be careful to include the *exact* error message when you ask on Stack Overflow, as giving the wrong error message can waste everyone's time.

Comment: By the way, what you want to do can be done in one line: `return sum(map(sum, list_of_lists))`.

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten the function `sum` with your variable of the same name. Rename the variable (I called it `total`) and it will work as expected.

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

def sum_lists(list_of_lists):
    result = []

    #extract what list from the bigger list
    for listnumber in list_of_lists:
        total = 0

        #add the value of the smaller list
        for value in listnumber:
            total += value
        result.append(total)

        #add the result values together
        #for resultvalue in result:
        #    result += resultvalue

    return sum(result)

print(sum_lists(list_of_lists))
```

There is nothing stopping you from using sum in the inner loop aswell.

```
def sum_lists(list_of_lists):
    result = []

    for listnumber in list_of_lists:

        result.append(sum(listnumber))

    return sum(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```
def sum_lists(list_of_lists):
   return sum([sum(lst) for lst in list_of_lists])
```

Comment: probably best to use a generator expression rather than a list comprehension here. I do like the conciseness of this tho...

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso yes agreed, but I think this is slightly clearer as to what is going on

Answer (score -2):

rename your variable "sum" since that is a reserved keyword